# Removing website entries from Google Chrome's Settings

Tags: google-chrome

Previously, I was able to delete web addresses stored in Chrome's Content Settings (Location, Popup, Full Screen, etc. See screenshot below) by hovering and clicking the `X` that appears. But today, when going through my settings, I noticed the `X` no longer appears when hovering, and it seems there isn't a way to remove these entries short of manually editing Chrome's Preferences file.

Does anyone know a way to remove these entries in the browser? Using the just released 44.0.2403.89 (64-bit) for Mac.

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't get that dialog box in Chrome 44.0.2403.89 (64-bit) for Mac. Mine is titled "Geolocation Exceptions" instead of "Location", and shows a table with "hostname pattern" and "behavior".

Comment: This is also much different from the Windows dialog for this. In the Windows dialog, highlighting an item will also add an `X` button to that item which will remove the item. PS: **To those about to answer this question, the OP is looking for a Mac solution; not a Windows solution.** Sorry, but they will certainly need to be told (at least) twice about that.

Comment: @krowe - I wish more people would say stuff like this.  I hate having to review answers, that simply said, are submitted without even reading the question.  At least there is a higher probability somebody won't do that.

Comment: So the problem was that I had enabled a flag (don't know which one) under chrome://flags. I reset everything to default, an I get the "normal" dialog.